# Magento 2 Static Blocks dont show up on category pages

Tags: magento2, blocks, magento2.2

I'm trying to add static blocks on Category Pages and all category pages have different content. So, I add Blocks to the Backend

> Category Page > Content > Add CMS Block

then,

> Display Settings > Static Block Only

In some Category, i am able to see the blocks but in some, it doesn't show no matter what the settings are. I'm unable to verify the problem.

For e.g - I made 2 blocks for Categories X and Y. Selected appropriate blocks for both. Block shows up in X but not on Y. All the settings are same. Even same blocks doesn't work

Comment: you need to check  / select appropriate store from store view drop down. i guess your default settings are overriding your store settings.

Comment: Custom modules and custom themes also can impact the way your category layout is rendered. Do you have any code that changes the category layout?

Comment: yes im currently using a theme for my site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

**EDIT:**

Try adding them as widgets maybe it will work. Go into the admin to **Content > Widgets > Add Widget**. From there you can configure your widgets to appear on Specific/All categories:

[image: Widget settings]

Comment: Done. Doesnt work :s

Comment: Have you tried adding the static blocks as Widgets?

Comment: Tried adding widgets and reindexed. Not working still

Answer (score 5):

On the category page go to Display Settings and change the 'Display Mode' to 'Static Block and Products'.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For those that can't find a resolution to this, I was pulling my hair out until I realised my static block was set to Disabled....

```
Content -> Blocks -> Select line and set Status to 'Enabled'
```

Worth mentioning maybe...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question. But whoever checking on this, please check configuration scope as well.
[image]
If something else is saved for the store you are checking on and you are changing default values, nothing will happen. (like mine)